# Colonna as cognomen

Tags: names, genitive

I am working on the Italian Renaissance soldier Stefano Colonna.
How would his name be written in Latin, as a label or signature,
Stephanus? What is the proper genitive for "of the Colonna family"?
Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

[According to Latin Wikipedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familia_Columnensis), the family was called **Familia Columnensis** or **gens Columnensis** in Latin.

The usage of Stephanus is [well attested](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=eMNUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP15&dq=Familia%20Columnensis%20stephanus&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Familia%20Columnensis%20stephanus&f=false) even within the context of this family. (There were sevaral Stephani in that family). So, judging by examples of other family members, this man in concern would be simply called **Stephanus Columna**.

To say that someone is of/from the family, I've encountered the usage of "**ex/de/e familia Columnensi**". which is the ablative case.

Comment: Congratulations for hitting a thousand points!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, Gratias tibi ago :)